# Visual Studio Code - write from right to left

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to write text on VSCode from right to left?
I mean that the start point of writing will be the top right of the editor window and twoards left side.
How?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145122

Comment: Thank you spikey. I reviewed some of the github topics on that matter, but couldn't understand if eventually it was supported and how to operate it.

Comment: Appears to be a missing feature.

Comment: @dushkin did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not officially supported. You can find and upvote issues related to it here:

- [Add right-to-left editing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4994)
- [Support for RTL languages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11770)

The 2nd issue mentions some temporary/permament workarounds, for example [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11770#issuecomment-1510465431) custom CSS solution:

> I've done something similar but it holds across VSCode resets. This is
> relevant to Markdown files.
>
> I've installed the extension: [vscode-custom-css](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) and followed the
> instructions [here](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) to add a CSS to my project's settings like this:
>
> `settings.json`:
>
> ```json
> "settings": {
>     // other settings...
>     //==== For RTL display 
>     // add rtl_css
>     "vscode_custom_css.imports": [
>       "file:///C:/<full_path>/rtl_css.css"
>     ],
>     // make bounded wordwrap to see all text both rtl and ltr in the same view
>     "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
>     "[markdown]": {
>       "editor.wordWrap": "bounded"
>     },
>     "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120
>     //===== end RTL display
> }
> ```
>
> `rtl_css.css`:
>
> ```css
> /* from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11770#issuecomment-1510465431 */
> .monaco-editor [dir="ltr"] {
>   direction: rtl;
>   float: right;
>   padding-right: 20px;
> }
>
> /* fix left-right mixup of some markdown features: bold, italic, strikethrough, `...` */
> .mtkb, .mtki, .mtks, .mtk11 {
>   unicode-bidi: isolate;
> }
> ```

Note that since it's not officially supported, it could easily break some extensions or other custom styling.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue so i made a extention for that in vscode,
here is the link of the extension [RTL extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SarbandAkray.rtl)
hope you like it and you can also contribute to it if you can ofcourse
Happy to help <3

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically your fix does to solve the problem?

Comment: While this is not spam, it is self promotion.  Please read the help on how to do it.  To avoid being labelled spam, you need to describe what your extension does, maybe provide screenshots if relevant.

Comment: @PeterSmith if you look at what they are asking and look how i answered you will creally see that i am not self promoting and i am just trying to be hlepfull on a subject that westren people dont give attention to with all due respect, just because i mentioned an extention thats done by me and its only one that can do that thing doesnt mean i am self promoting, and i get why you would think its self promoting or spam because english isnt my first language so iam sorry if my writing suggests that i am slef promoting because i am not trying to do that